# Make setTimeout Call Itself, Until Condition is True

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, autocomplete, settimeout

I have an input-field inside a form, which class changes dynamically, depending on an ajax-script (which i can not modify) from "foo" to "foo bar" back to "foo". I would like to modify the style of the field, when it's length is > 0, it's value does not contain "nid" and it's class is not "bar". 
My first idea was to have a setTimeout, that gets called every time the input field's class is "bar", until it is "foo". But i do not know whether this is good practice, nor how to do it …

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing would be to bind the change or keydown event on the element to catch if the contents of the field matches.

If it matches you add a class fx `baz`, if it doesn't matches you remove that class.

That would make it possible for you to style the element with CSS. Make a rule with the class `bar` that will override the rule with the class `baz`.

Answer (score 1):

use `keyup` event of input `field`

Comment: Your answer replies only to 1 of 3 conditions … »I would like to modify the style of the field, when it's length is > 0, it's value does not contain "nid" and it's class is not "bar"«. Especially the class-Problem keeps my mind muddled …

Answer (score 0):

Doing that's fine. Or you can use setInterval which will fire repeatedly, then call clearInterval once the condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look [my jQuery plugin](http://whattheheadsaid.com/projects/input-special-event) for detecting user input.  It normalizes the HTML5 `oninput` event across all the major browsers so it can detect input from keyboards, spelling corrections, pasting, dragging & dropping, etc.

Using that plugin, your code might look something like this:

```
$("#myInput").input(function () {
    var $this = $(this), val = this.value;
    if (val.length && val.indexOf("nid") === -1 && !$this.hasClass("bar"))
        $this.css("color", "red");
    else
        $this.css("color", "green");
});
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hVDP8/**

`oninput` has many benefits over using timers or the `onkeyup` event, such as code execution before the new value is painted on the screen.  In fact, it's perfect for this type of situation.